# Image / File AJAX form fields not saving

Tags: forms, ajax, media, users

I built a AJAX form so that users can setup their user profiles after logging in. All basic text fields work/update fine. But I can't for the life of me get a image field (Picture) or file field (PDF Resume) to save.

The appropriate widget is displayed, and it allows me to upload the files (both image, and pdf) no problem. I can even see a preview of the image once it's uploaded. The files are definitely in the media section of the content admin page. BUT when I refresh the ajax form page the fields are empty again. Why is it not applying the uploads to the users profile fields?

All other fields update fine.

The form:

```
<form action="<?php print $ajax_form['#action']; ?>" method="post" id="<?php print $ajax_form['#id']; ?>-header" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<?php print render($ajax_form['user']['field_user_picture']); ?>
<?php print render($ajax_form['user']['field_resume']); ?>

<div class="single-line">
<?php print render($ajax_form['user']['field_user_first_name']['und'][0]) ?>
<?php print render($ajax_form['user']['field_user_last_name']['und'][0]) ?>
</div>

<?php print render($ajax_form['user']['field_user_title']['und'][0]) ?>
<?php print render($ajax_form['user']['field_user_location']['und'][0]) ?>
<?php print render($ajax_form['user']['field_user_summary']['und'][0]) ?>
<?php print render($ajax_form['form_build_id']); ?>
<?php print render($ajax_form['form_token']); ?>
<?php print render($ajax_form['form_id']); ?>
<?php print render($ajax_form['actions']); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="part" value="header"/>
</form>
```

and then:

```
 $form['account'] = array(
 '#type' => 'value',
 '#value' => $account,
 );

 $form['#action'] = '/ajax/' . $id . '/' . $type;
 $form['#id'] = 'ajax-form';

 $form_key = 'user';
 $form[$form_key] = array(
'#type' => 'fieldset',
'#title' => 'none',
'#parents' => array($form_key),
);
field_attach_form('user', $account, $form[$form_key], $form_state, LANGUAGE_NONE);
```

Thank you VERY kindly in advance,
Alex